# How to best convert json or dict to object and back?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, python-dataclasses

Suppose I have some data (could be `json` or `dict`) that's arbitrarily structured in some relatively complicated way like the `example` dictionary in the sample code below.

```py
from dataclasses import asdict, dataclass, field
from typing import Any, List


@dataclass
class NameValue:
    name: str
    value: Any


@dataclass
class Category:
    filters: List[NameValue] = field(default_factory=list)
    description: Any = field(default=None)


@dataclass
class Container:
    id: int
    categories: List[Category] = field(default_factory=list)

    def __post_init__(self):
        if self.categories:
            self.categories = [Category(**category) for category in self.categories]

    def do_stuff(self, arg: str) -> None:
        """Do stuff with arg."""

        print(f"Doing stuff with {arg}")
        return None


def main():

    example = {
        "id": 1,
        "categories": [
            {
                "filters": [
                    {"name": "two", "value": 2},
                    {"name": "three", "value": 3},
                    {"name": "four", "value": 4},
                ],
                "description": "Kick it!",
            },
            {
                "filters": [
                    {"name": "five", "value": 5},
                    {"name": "six", "value": 6},
                    {"name": "seven", "value": 7},
                    {"name": "eight", "value": 8},
                ],
                "description": "Something to appreciate.",
            },
        ],
    }

    container = Container(**example)
    container.do_stuff("this thing")

    assert asdict(container) == example

    return None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I want to be able to easily work with the data in the form of objects so I get access to the benefits of oop.

My thinking as to how to do that was to generate an object by passing an unpacked dictionary to the `Container` class, manipulate those objects, then return them to `dict`s and/or `json` strings as necessary.

The script runs fine in this example, but given some issues I've experienced with this approach (slow performance, default value quagmires, etc.), I have this nagging feeling there's probably a better (i.e., more efficient, pythonic, etc.) way of accomplishing this?

Thanks in advance for any helpful advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of thing is sometimes called "boxing" - and using this to google for a package, you can find some libraries that can do that ready to install on Pypi.

"performance" from your approach should not be too strong a concern, however - but some libs can likely keep the underlying data structures and lazily fetch the requested fields - if you are processing tens of thousands of such objects and only actually consuming a fraction of the fields when they are Python objects, that might make a difference - not otherwise: for retrieving all fields in a dict its contents will have to be copied around anyway.

Otherwise, if you don't want to use a 3rdy party library, some recursive code to to that for any arbitrary object parsed from JSON is somewhat easy to do in Python - the code bellow will work. If you want to parse to and from specific pre-defined classes, hadcoded in Python files, you have to take the manual approach you showed here.

This will work for an arbitrary JSON structure, without the need to declare any classes in Python:

```
from collections.abc import Mapping, Sequence

class Box:
    def __init__(self, _data):
        self._data = _data
    def __dir__(self):
        return sorted(self._data.keys()) if isinstance(self._data, dict) else dir(self._data)
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if not isinstance(self._data, Mapping):
            return self._data
        try:
            value = self._data[name]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(name)
        if isinstance(value, (Mapping, Sequence)) and not isinstance(data, (str, bytes)) :
            value = type(self)(value)
        return value

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        # provided mostly to enable access to list elements
        value = self._data[key]
        if isinstance(value, (Mapping, Sequence))  and not isinstance(data, (str, bytes)):
            return type(self)(value)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._data)
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name.startswith("_"):
            return super().__setattr__(name, value)
        if isinstance(value, Box):
            value = value._data
        self._data[name] = value
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Box({self._data!r})"
```

And here is how your example data works with this class
in an interactive shell:

```
In [22]: ee = Box(example)

In [23]: dir(ee)
Out[23]: ['categories', 'data', 'id']

In [24]: ee.data
Out[24]: Box({'id': 1, 'categories': [{'filters': [{'name': 'two', 'value': 2}, {'name': 'three', 'value': 3}, {'name': 'four', 'value': 4}], 'description': 'Kick it!'}, {'filters': [{'name': 'five', 'value': 5}, {'name': 'six', 'value': 6}, {'name': 'seven', 'value': 7}, {'name': 'eight', 'value': 8}], 'description': 'Something to appreciate.'}], 'data': {...}})

In [25]: ee.categories[0].filters[0].name
Out[25]: Box('two')
```